# Force SSL .htaccess Only For WWW not any other subdomain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl

I've been working with many rules for forcing SSL via .htaccess, but I can't find one that will only force for "www" and not any other subdomain.

In example :

www.website.com - OK

blog.website.com - Not OK

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} ^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond {HTTP_HOST} !^www\.website\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: It looks like that's not forcing the SSL. The ideal solution is it forces ssl and if its not www then it forces http

Comment: see updated code now and make sure it is **first rule** in your .htaccess. Hope you're not running any CMS/PHP framework.

Comment: In that case it must be very first rule itself.